# Is hypocrisy considered bad on SO?

Tags: discussion

A new user posts a low-quality answer; for example, let's just say that the user's answer is code-only. As you know, code-only answers are best backed up by explanatory text. You post a comment warning them and asking them to elaborate on their answer.

The problem is that you had a few poor answers yourself. You have made this mistake (let's say a few times). You have been doing a little better (i.e. you learned the hard way), but you still have that history. Does that make you hypocritical in posting that comment. Would that be considered bad to do?

Comment: Isn't hypocrisy considered bad *everywhere*?

Comment: Call them out on it on their own posts. You both improve your posts. Win-win.

Comment: If you feel guilty, you can admit to it and use yourself as an example. *"Code-only answers are generally frowned upon here. I used to do it as well, but I realized that answers without an explanation are more difficult to understand."* I don't see how that's bad. You are just being honest and spreading the word. "I learned this too" is not really hypocrisy, at least the way I see it.

Comment: What you describe seems hardly hypocrisy.

Comment: I think you're operating on an invalid premise here. Comments pointing out problems with an answer are made to **help** the poster make their answer better. I greatly appreciate it when people point out problems or mistakes in my answers, as long as the comments are constructive. And I hope that my comments are interpreted the same way.

Comment: Hypocrisy should be considered irrelevant. Questions, answers and comments are upvoted or downvoted based on their individual merits. Caring about personal "hypocrisy" would imply caring about the person rather than the post.

Comment: Even if you are aware of your own faults, doesn't mean you can do something about them, is that grounds not to help someone else? I have much more trouble reviewing my own (boring) texts, including posts on [se] sites, than I have with reviewing those of others. I don't think that  medical doctors who smoke are overweight and recommend others to not smoke cq. eat healthy are hypocrites either.

Comment: Your title could use a little work... Consider making it a little more specific, so that others might find it a little more easily.

Answer (score 13):

Helping folks understand what constitutes a low-quality answer and how to improve their contributions is great, because it helps them improve their future (and current) answers. If you can provide feedback in a constructive manner, I think that's a benefit to the community. I don't think your decision to help others understand how to improve should be affected by the quality of your previous answers.

That being said, if you have come to realize that some of your previous answers are low quality, it could be good to go back through them and edit/delete them as appropriate. Now you've done a second good thing for the site -- improving the quality of your own contributions. Further, you no longer need to feel hypocritical about your feedback to others.

Answer (score 5):

> Does that make you hypocritical in posting that comment.

You know the answer to that. Of course it does. The more important question is, now that you've realized it, what are you going to do about it?

There are two extremes to the spectrum of responses that one can expect in such situations. On the one extreme, you can completely ignore your imperfections and point out others' imperfections. On the other extreme, you go about removing your imperfections to the complete exclusion of not pointing out anybody else's imperfections, however major they might be.

We all lie somewhere in between. Pick your place in the middle and stay where you are comfortable.